# past participle clause at the end of a sentence

Tags: expressions

From my observation, past participle clauses are usually used at the beginning or right after the main subject. But is it natural to use it at the end of a sentence?

E.g.,
The car has stopped moving, fueled by insufficient gasoline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be judged on a case-by-case basis, but in general there is no reason why such a clause—a past-participial nonfinite clause functioning as a supplement—couldn't go to the end of the sentence. There are lots of attested examples:

*“Hey!” Isabelle shouted, e͟n͟r͟a͟g͟e͟d͟ ͟t͟o͟ ͟s͟e͟e͟ ͟F͟r͟a͟n͟n͟i͟e͟ ͟s͟k͟i͟n͟n͟i͟n͟g͟ ͟d͟o͟w͟n͟ ͟t͟h͟e͟ ͟s͟t͟e͟p͟s͟ ͟o͟f͟ ͟t͟h͟e͟ ͟c͟h͟i͟l͟d͟r͟e͟n͟'͟s͟ ͟r͟o͟o͟m͟.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=IOUVBgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT56&dq=%22shouted%2C%20enraged%22&pg=PT56#v=onepage&q=%22shouted,%20enraged%22&f=false)
*We just stopped, e͟x͟h͟a͟u͟s͟t͟e͟d͟.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=3Bvw1DOR_F4C&lpg=PA88&dq=%22stopped%2C%20exhausted%22&pg=PA88#v=onepage&q=%22stopped,%20exhausted%22&f=false)
*He dropped the rose across her breasts and left, d͟i͟s͟a͟p͟p͟o͟i͟n͟t͟e͟d͟ ͟t͟h͟a͟t͟ ͟h͟e͟ ͟h͟a͟d͟n͟'͟t͟ ͟b͟e͟e͟n͟ ͟a͟b͟l͟e͟ ͟t͟o͟ ͟w͟a͟t͟c͟h͟ ͟h͟e͟r͟ ͟e͟y͟e͟s͟.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ns12IAQj2-sC&lpg=PA101&dq=%22left%2C%20disappointed%20that%22&pg=PA101#v=onepage&q=%22left,%20disappointed%20that%22&f=false)